# Detect arrow key being pressed while an `input()` is running in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a REPL for a programming language, and I want to allow arrow keys to cycle through past inputs, much like the official Python REPL does. In order to take user input, I'm doing something like this:

```py
code = input(" > ")
# stuff here to process the code
```

However, I can't figure out how to get this to detect up/down arrow keys being pressed as well. How can I manage this?

Comment: Use the `readline` library instead of `input()`. That will allow you to customize keystrokes.

Comment: you could look at the standard library curses https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/curses.html# and as an example of up down left right https://www.codehaven.co.uk/python/using-arrow-keys-with-inputs-python/

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
        print("Down Arrow key pressed")
```

Comment: How would you use this to cycle through past inputs? There's no way to stuff the previous lines into the input buffer. It seems like you just read the title without reading the question that explains why they need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard library for registering keystrokes. You may have to install the module into your REPL.
https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

from there you can import it and check if the key has been pressed.
For example, if you are waiting for a keypress of the left or right arrow

```
import keyboard 
     
while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('right'):
        pass # code to cycle right 

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
        pass   # code to cycle left

    #check if enter is clicked to procede 
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        break

#continue code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class REPL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []
        self.current_index = -1
        self.current_input = ""

    def handle_input(self, key):
        if key == "up":
            if self.current_index < len(self.history) - 1:
                self.current_index += 1
                self.current_input = self.history[self.current_index]
        elif key == "down":
            if self.current_index > 0:
                self.current_index -= 1
                self.current_input = self.history[self.current_index]
        else:
            # Handle other key presses (e.g., alphanumeric characters)
            self.current_input += key

        # Process the current input
        self.process_input()

    def process_input(self):
        # Evaluate and print the current input
        print("Evaluated:", self.current_input)

        # Add the current input to history if not empty
        if self.current_input.strip():
            self.history.insert(0, self.current_input)
            self.current_index = -1
            self.current_input = ""


# Example usage
repl = REPL()
while True:
    user_input = input(">>> ")
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        break
    else:
        repl.handle_input(user_input)
```